# Aliasing frequently used patterns in Lex

Tags: parsing, lex, lexical-analysis

I have one regexp, which is used in a several rules. Can I define alias for it, to keep this regexp definition in one place and just use it across the code?
Example:

```
[A-Za-z0-9].[A-Za-z0-9_-]* (expression) NAME (alias)
...
%%
NAME[=]NAME {
  //Do something.
}
%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes in the [definitions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Format.html) section of your lex input file (before the `%%`) and you use it in a regular expression by putting the name inside curly braces (`{…}`). For example:

```
name        [A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]*

%%

{name}[=]{name}  { /* Do something */ }
```